# Vue.js - Dynamically create slots from filtered scopedSlots

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

Thanks to Vue.js [Scoped Slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Scoped-Slots), I'm able to loop over all available slots in the Child component.
Now, what I try to do is to render **only the slots beginning with a certain string** on a specific place in the template.

Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I'm probably overlooking something.

**Parent.vue:**

```html
<Child>
    <template #table--item.person_id="{ value }">
        <div class="text-caption">{{ value }}</div>
    </template>
</Child>
```

**Child.vue:**

```js
<template>
    <v-data-table>
        <template v-for="(_, slotName) of tableSlots" v-slot:[slotName]="scope">
            <slot :name="slotName" v-bind="scope"></slot>
        </template>
    </v-data-table>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        computed: {
            tableSlots() {
                const prefix = 'table--';
                const raw = this.$scopedSlots;
                const filtered = Object.keys(raw)
                    .filter(key => key.startsWith(prefix))
                    .reduce((obj, key) => ({
                        ...obj,
                        [key.replace(prefix, "")]: raw[key]
                    }), {});
                return filtered;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-bose-yi8x0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parent tries to access a slot named `table--item.glutenfree` and so a scoped slot is created with that name.  But when you filter in order to target the corresponding `v-data-table` slot, you also use that filtered name for the child slot:

```
key.replace(prefix, "")
```

The parent can't access the child slot because the parent is targeting a name with the prefix still intact.

Change the slot in the child component:

```html
<slot :name="`table--${slotName}`" v-bind="scope"></slot>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I think you misunderstood the question. Of course it would work if you would leave out `table--` and remove all logic in the computed property. But how would I be able then to render only the table-- slots at a specific place in Child.vue?

Comment: I'll try to be more clear: `v-data-table` does indeed need a slot called `item.glutenfree`. The `table--` prefix, however, is just so I can render the slots prefixed with `table--` at a specific place.

Comment: I might have. Still, the child creates a slot name without the prefix that the parent can't access using the prefix.  Will all columns be targeted?  If not, what do you want to happen when a column slot isn't targeted?

Comment: In App.vue, we call the `genericTable` component and pass a slot to it named `table--item.glutenfree`.
Now, in the `genericTable.vue` component, we can access this slot via `this.$scopedSlots`.  The computed property `tableSlots()` transforms the `this.$scopedSlots` to a filtered version of all slots starting with `table--`. As soon as we have these slots, we can remove the prefix so it would have the correct slot name in the `<v-data-table>`. I think it's doing the right ding as you can see in the console.log I inserted in the mounted hook. Nevertheless, it doesn't work...

Comment: It will use the right name when targeting `v-data-table` but it will also create a slot by that filtered name for the parent to target, but the parent is using the prefix.  You need this:  `<slot :name="'table--' + slotName" v-bind="scope"></slot>`.  I updated my answer to make this clearer.